# Pyspark load-csv does not show the real schema of a new file (only the "infered" schema)

Tags: pyspark, schema, databricks, partitioning

I'm trying to load with pyspark csv from a partitionned folder : mnt/data/test/ingestdatetime=20210208/test_20210208.csv

```
df = spark.read.csv("mnt/data/test")
df = df.filter(df['ingestdatetime'] == '20210208')
```

Basically I want to see if the schema is different from what it is supposed to be (the data does not come with headers, so i can not compare headers)

The issue is that, whenever I’m loading the data on top level "data/test/", the schema is “inferred” based on few rows, and it does not see if the new file have additional columns or too many columns.
==> So i am not able to compare if the schema are different.

I see this (6 columns):
[image]

Instead of this (7 columns):
[image]

The first way i could do it, is to load the data directly from the partition (data/test/ingestdate=20210208/) . But i would lose the partition key column type.

I guess i could also load everything as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `basePath` option when reading with PySpark to "keep" the partition column in the output dataframe. This option is well-known but undocumented (or [documented only for Parquet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html) but applicable with all other sources )

```
spark.read.option("basePath", "/mnt/data/test").csv("/mnt/data/test/ingestdate=20210208")
```